# How to use service layer in MVP in asp.net web forms?

Tags: asp.net, mvp

I use MVP for my application ( asp.net web forms) , i want to use service layer but i don't know where is use it ?
The service layer can talk to Model ? 
Or better when Presenter only talk to Model and Call Presenter in Service layer ?
Thanks .

Comment: for which purpose you adding service layer ?

Comment: Please be descriptive so that we can help you out.

Comment: i wana to add Service layer for Ajax . in my application many item must validate with ajax request so i need to service layer for use it ( asmx , wcf ) .

Comment: is your service layer call to database or not ?

Comment: i have a lot of ajax request in my application so i need to have  web service for  ajax request  . so where is declare this web service ?  
i used  in Service layer  so where is best place Service layer in my application ?

Comment: Yes . My service require to communicate with database.
Is service layer can talk to Model in MVP ? Or can talk only with Presenter ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MVP - Presenter and the Service Layer - Where to declare Service Layer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5451590/mvp-presenter-and-the-service-layer-where-to-declare-service-layer)